# Is there a possibility to apply Moni Naor and Adi Shamir's "visual cryptography" on text ( paragraph)?

Tags: encryption, decryption, visual-cryptography

[[Instead of two images I want to consider two paragraphs(text) when combined should give me a secret message]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiRmB.png)

In their algorithm, the image has been split into two component **images**. Each component image has a pair of pixels for every pixel in the original image. These pixel pairs are shaded black or white according to the following rule: if the original image pixel was black, the pixel pairs in the component images must be complementary; randomly shade one ■□, and the other □■. When these complementary pairs are overlapped, they will appear dark gray. On the other hand, if the original image pixel was white, the pixel pairs in the component images must match: both ■□ or both □■. When these matching pairs are overlapped, they will appear light gray.

What I would like to do is play around with text watermarking and use text instead of the image! So for images, you can consider pixel values similarly for ***text*** what can I consider and how can I similar idea (Algorithm) to the piece of text?

Comment: Yes, years ago they already show it in the ramp session of a conference ( probably that was the ASIACrypt.

Comment: @kelalaka, do you happen to remember more? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @AmanGrewal Let me check, I would like to have it when they show it, too... and give some time.

Comment: @AmanGrewal what did they showed was close to the Wikipedia's version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_cryptography

Comment: @kelalaka, I see. So the basic idea is to just convert text to an image first

Comment: Yes, You can think of it as symmetric encryption.